# How to set 'Display Product Options In' = 'Block After Info Column' globally

Tags: product-attribute

By default, Products options are shown in Product Info Box. If you want to show them below the info box, either

**1 You have to edit xml layout update: catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    ...
    <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>1</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
    <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>1</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
</block>
```

Drawback of this approach is we can't override in local.xml. It has to be edited in the catalog.xml file itself.

**2 or run SQL update as:**

```
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$this->startSetup();
// get options_container attribute and update its value to 'container2' for configurable products
$attribute = $this->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'options_container');
if (!empty($attribute['attribute_id'])) {
    $this->run("
        UPDATE {$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity_varchar')}
        SET value = 'container2'
        WHERE
            entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM {$this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')} WHERE type_id='configurable')
            AND attribute_id={$attribute['attribute_id']}
    ");
}

$this->endSetup();
```

I am just looking for third approach which works via local.xml layout update.

Comment: I am a bit confused here are you not missing the section of code that actually displays the information, all I can see is the unset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<reference>` directive in the `local.xml` layout update, which should do the trick:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>1</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
        <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>1</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I already tried that but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
    ->getAllIds();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $productIds,
    array('options_container' => 'container2'),
    0
)
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. That's definitely the better approach for updating the options_container. It would be even better if we can set the value temporarily via local.xml so that product added in future are in the same container.